# Create gridview that adds in data (number of records) dynamically

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I need something to hold the search results and I'm thinking of using gridview (or maybe a table). When user performed a search, search results will be shown in a table format. Something like:
[image]

The column attributes are fixed. But the number of records returned may be different and the gridview (or table) must be expanded accordingly. The max records at one page will be 10 and I need to do Paging at the bottom as well.

In this gridview (or table), user can click on the ID to select the result for other purposes. I have to cater that requirement too.

I'm using MVC with html and css. Please help! I am really new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at the WebGrid helper: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx